# Polygon not showing

Tags: polygon, vector, openlayers-2

I am trying to draw a polygon on my map but it's not showing, I do not have a js error on the console...

Here is the code :

```
     var style = {
       strokeColor: "#00FF00",
       strokeOpacity: 1,
       strokeWidth: 3,
       fillColor: "#00FF00",
       fillOpacity: 0.8
    }; 
    var points = [];

    var p1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(49.4, -1.15);
    var p2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(49.4, -0.92);
    var p4 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(49.23, -1.15);
    var p3 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(49.23, -0.92);
    points.push(p1,p2,p3,p4);
    var ring = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(points);
    var polygon = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([ring]);

    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(polygon, null, style);
    console.log(polygon);
    var line_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Test");
    line_layer.addFeatures([feature]);
    viewer.getMap().addLayer(line_layer);
```

Tell me if you see anything wrong !

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Could you update your answer to include the js error you are getting.

Comment: Sorry I meant I have no error on my js console.

Comment: What does the `console.log(polygon);` call display?

Answer (score 1):

I have found my error, I got to transform lat lon into point and I have reversed lat and long ... :

```
        var p4 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-1.15, 49.41).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
    var p3 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-0.92, 49.41).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
    var p2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-0.92, 49.23).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
    var p1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-1.15, 49.23).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
```